# Can gdal2tiles create tiles at zoom levels > 10?

Tags: gdal, tiles, tile-map-service, gdal2tiles

I am trying to create tiles from tif images using the gdal2tiles command (at the OSGeo4W command line). I've been asked if it would be possible to create tiles at zoom level 12. Using the -z switch like so ...

```
gdal2tiles --s_srs EPSG:32717 -z 12 input_tif.tif output_folder
```

This creates the tiles but they are all black. I suspect this cannot be done but I'd like to confirm that I'm not just having an unrelated problem. Tiles created at 1-10 appear to be ok with most of my input files.

Comment: I had no problem generating tiles up to z16. What do you get from `--zoom 8-12` ?

Comment: It appears that the way I had done it, it DOES work (I may have missed that there was data there when zoomed in because of the small area of valid data). Running it at 8-16 helped me to see the data. Thanks! It appears that the answer to my question is "Yes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in doubt, apply a zoom level option of `--zoom 8-12` and check all resulting output folders.

It always worked for me with this option.